# How to use Ramda to solve hour format?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am new to functional programming and after learning the basics of functional programming and Ramda, I decided to get my hands dirty by replacing some of the functions written previously using imperative programming. I decided to rewrite function to execute a simple task

Convert `13:22 to 1:22 PM`

Here is the code I wrote after a lot of mind wrapping

```
const formatHr = (R.cond([
  [R.lt(R.__,13), R.identity],
  [R.gte(R.__,13), R.subtract(R.__,12)],
]));

const updateHr = x => {
  const hr = parseInt(R.head(x));
  const newHr = formatHr(hr);
  const newX = R.update(0, newHr, x);
  const meridiem = R.ifElse(R.lt(R.__,12),x => R.identity('AM'), x => R.identity('PM'))(hr);
  return `${R.join(':',newX)} ${meridiem}`
}

const getHour = R.pipe(R.split(':'), updateHr);
const hr = getHour('13:22'); // 1:22 PM
```

It just seems way too complicated for something that can be easily written in vanilla javascript with ES6 syntax. Can someone show me how it's done efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we definitely could improve on that with Ramda tools, there seems very little reason to do so.  I think your goal is a bit misguided.  Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of its authors) is designed to offer you tools that help you code a certain way.  It is not a new dialect of JS into which you should convert all your code.

I would write this function something like this:

```js
const formatHour = (time) => {
  const [h, m] = time .split (':')
  return `${h > 12 ? h - 12 : h}:${m} ${h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`
}


console .log (formatHour ('13:22'))
```

The main points I check when I want to ensure that I'm writing functional code is whether what I'm writing involves no mutation of data (usually that includes not reassigning variables, although sometime I will do so for performance reasons) and that I only have pure functions -- those that always return the same output for the same input and have no side-effect.  This function passes both tests.  We don't mutate anything, and we assign `h` and `m` only once, without reassignment.  The function relies only on its arguments to compute a consistent result, while never affecting anything outside.

There are some other features that I prefer when writing functional code, but these are less important and possibly more controversial.  I don't like to have many intermediate variable, and if they're only used once, I often inline them.  Thus I prefer the version above to this one:

```js
const formatHour = (time) => {
  const [hour, minute] = time .split (':')
  const newHour = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour
  const meridian = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'
  return `${newHour}:${minute} ${meridian}`
}
```

But that's a minor preference, and I will often choose the other way if my code starts to feel unreadable without helper local variables.  The other one, though, I try to do as often as I can: I prefer to work with pure expressions rather than statements.  I will use conditional statements (ternaries) over `if`-statements.  I will choose single-expression bodies to arrow functions over `{`-`}`-delimited blocks.

That would tempt me to write this function this way:

```js
const formatHour = (time, [h, m] = time .split (':')) => 
  `${h > 12 ? h - 12 : h}:${m} ${h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`;
```

And often I do such things.  But default parameters used like this can be a headache too.  Using the earlier versions of the function, I could write

```js
['7:04', '11:59', '12:01', '13:22'] .map (formatHour)
//=> ["7:04 AM", "11:59 AM", "12:01 PM", "1:22 PM"]
```

But this won't work in this latest version.  `Array.prototype.map` supplies two additional parameters beyond the current item: its index and the entire array.  So in this last version, if we pass it to `map`, the `[h, m]` parameters are not well-formed since there is an integer index in that spot and not an array.  We'll get some sort of destructuring error.  We could choose to fix this by adding several unused parameters, with something like this:

```js
const formatHour = (time, _, __, [h, m] = time .split (':')) => 
  `${h > 12 ? h - 12 : h}:${m} ${h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`;

['7:04', '11:59', '12:01', '13:22'] .map (formatHour)
//=> ["7:04 AM", "11:59 AM", "12:01 PM", "1:22 PM"]
```

But that seems clunky.  I do this sometimes, especially for internal functions.  But when you don't know how your function will be used in the wild, it's a risk.

---

Ramda offers no improvements on this that I can see.

But, if I were to try to do this with Ramda functions, I might do it a bit differently than you do.

First of all, there's some simpler alternatives to Ramda's [`cond`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) when you are only dealing with a single case, [`ifElse`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ifElse).  But even that might be overkill when one of 
your branches simply returns the data intact.  Then you can use [`when`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#when) (or its counterpart, [`unless`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unless)) to transform the data when a condition is met and leave it alone otherwise.

Secondly, I would probably use the [`evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) function to let me alter one part of my data structure (an array with `hour` and `minute` properties) but leave the other part(s) alone.

Finally, because I have to use the hour in two places and combine their results into a single one, I would use [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) or, even better when possible, [`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) to manage this.

```js
const formatHour = pipe (
  split (':'),
  lift (([h, m], meridian) => `${h}:${m} ${meridian}`) (
    evolve ([when (gt (__, 12), subtract (__, 12))]),
    ([h, m]) => h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'
  )
);

console .log (
  ['7:04', '11:59', '12:01', '13:22'] .map (formatHour)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, split, lift, evolve, when, gt, __, subtract} = R   </script>
```

Note that I don't try to make this entirely point-free.  I could move that way by replacing

```js
    ([h, m]) => h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'
```

with

```js
    ifElse(pipe(head, gte(__, 12)), always('PM'), always('AM'))
```

and I'm sure we could do something even uglier for

```js
    ([h, m], meridian) => `${h}:${m} ${meridian}`
```

But I don't see any point in it.  We are *reducing* readability here and it would get even worse if we tried the other one.

And that's the point.  Ramda is a tool.  Use it when it improves something important in your code: readability, maintainability, performance, or something else tangible.  But don't use it simply because it's available and already included in your project.  The goal should never be, "*How do I make this work using Ramda?*" unless you are working on learning Ramda.  The goals should include simplicity, maintainability, performance, etc.  If Ramda helps you fill these goals, great.  Skip it when it doesn't.

### A late thought

I've just realized that none of the above handle the midnight hour correctly.  Presumably you want `"00:35"` to become `"12:35 AM"`, and that would take a minor tweak of all the versions above.  The first one would become

```js
const formatHour = (time) => {
  const [h, m] = time .split (':')
  return `${h > 12 ? h - 12 : h == 0 ? 12 : h}:${m} ${h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`
}
```

And similar changes would need to be applied to the others.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It definitely helps when I think about how to integrate Ramda in our projects

Comment: I'm so appreciative you take the time to explain your reasoning with such fine detail. I forgot about Ramda's `__` which makes partial application nice here. NB this answer incorrectly displays [24:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00) as `12:00 PM`

Answer (score 2):

I would use R.applySpec after splitting, because each mapping function has access to all original values.

I wouldn't use Ramda for the mapping functions (`normalizeHour`, and `amPm`), since destructuring and literal templates would be easier to use, and readable as well.

After formatting the values, get them using R.props (R.values would work as well, but it's less explicit), and join the values.

```js
const { pipe, split, applySpec, props, join } = R 

const normalizeHour = ([m]) => m > 12 ? m - 12 : m
const amPm = ([h, m]) => `${m} ${h >= 12 && h < 24 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`

const formatHour = pipe(
  split(':'),
  applySpec({
    h: normalizeHour,
    m: amPm,
  }),
  props(['h', 'm']),
  join(' ')
);

console.log(
  ['7:04', '11:59', '12:01', '13:22', '24:53'].map(formatHour)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: NB this incorrectly displays [24:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00) as `12:00 PM`

Comment: @Thankyou the user formerly known as pocahontas :)

Comment: Awesome @OriDrori, I did not know about the applySpec function. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

**midnight 00:00 and 24:00**

> In the 24-hour time notation, the day begins at midnight, 00:00, and the last minute of the day begins at 23:59. Where convenient, the notation 24:00 may also be used to refer to midnight at the end of a given date[5] — that is, 24:00 of one day is the same time as 00:00 of the following day.
>
> The notation 24:00 mainly serves to refer to the exact end of a day in a time interval. A typical usage is giving opening hours ending at midnight (e.g. "00:00–24:00", "07:00–24:00"). Similarly, some bus and train timetables show 00:00 as departure time and 24:00 as arrival time. Legal contracts often run from the start date at 00:00 until the end date at 24:00.
>
> While the 24-hour notation unambiguously distinguishes between midnight at the start (00:00) and end (24:00) of any given date, there is no commonly accepted distinction among users of the 12-hour notation. Style guides and military communication regulations in some English-speaking countries discourage the use of 24:00 even in the 24-hour notation, and recommend reporting times near midnight as 23:59 or 00:01 instead.[6] Sometimes the use of 00:00 is also avoided.[6] In variance with this, the correspondence manual for the United States Navy and United States Marine Corps formerly specified 0001 to 2400.[7] The manual was updated in June 2015 to use 0000 to 2359

**times after 24:00**

> Time-of-day notations beyond 24:00 (such as **24:01** or **25:00** instead of **00:01** or **01:00**) are not commonly used and not covered by the relevant standards. However, they have been used occasionally in some special contexts in the United Kingdom, France, Spain, Canada, Japan, South Korea, Hong Kong and China where business hours extend beyond midnight, such as broadcast television production and scheduling.

(citation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock)

---

**our program**

Other answers here discuss some of the trade-offs we make when choosing to express our program in different ways. In this answer I specifically want to focus on implementing a robust formatter that accommodates the variations outlined above. We will write `format24`, which takes a 24-hour time string and a formatting function, and expect it to work like so -

```js
format24("00:00", to12) //=> "12:00 AM"
format24("11:59", to12) //=> "11:59 AM"
format24("12:01", to12) //=> "12:01 PM"
format24("13:22", to12) //=> "1:22 PM"
format24("24:00", to12) //=> "12:00 AM"
format24("25:01", to12) //=> "1:01 AM"
```

The formatting function, `to12` in this example, accepts a 0-23 `hour` and a 0-59 `minute` -

```js
const to12 = (h = 0, m = 0) =>
  `${formatHour(h % 12)}:${formatMinute(m)} ${formatMeridian(h)}`

const formatHour = (h = 0) =>
  h === 0 ? "12" : String(h)

const formatMinute = (m = 0) =>
  m < 10 ? `0${m}` : String(m)

const formatMeridian = (h = 0) =>
  h < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"
```

Finally, we implement `format24` -

```js
const format24 = (time = "00:00", formatter = String) =>
{ const [ _, h = 0, m = 0 ] =
    time.match(/^(\d?\d):(\d\d)/) || []

  const minutes =
    Number(h) * 60 + Number(m)

  return formatter
    ( Math.floor(minutes / 60) % 24 // 0-23
    , minutes % 60                  // 0-59
    )
}
```

**verify it works correctly**

```js
const times =
  [ "00:00", "00:01", "01:23", "11:59", "12:00", "12:01", "13:22", "23:59", "24:00", "24:01", "25:00", "27:45" ]

times.forEach(t => console.log(t, "->", format24(t, to12)))
```

Input -> Output

```
00:00 -> 12:00 AM
00:01 -> 12:01 AM
01:23 -> 1:23 AM
11:59 -> 11:59 AM
12:00 -> 12:00 PM
12:01 -> 12:01 PM
13:22 -> 1:22 PM
23:59 -> 11:59 PM
24:00 -> 12:00 AM
24:01 -> 12:01 AM
25:00 -> 1:00 AM
27:45 -> 3:45 AM
```

---

**code demo**

Expand the snippet below to verify the results of `format24` in your own browser -

```js
const format24 = (time = "00:00", formatter = String) =>
{ const [ _, h = 0, m = 0 ] =
    time.match(/^(\d?\d):(\d\d)/) || []

  const minutes =
    Number(h) * 60 + Number(m)

  return formatter
    ( Math.floor(minutes / 60) % 24
    , minutes % 60
    )
}

const to12 = (h = 0, m = 0) =>
  `${formatHour(h % 12)}:${formatMinute(m)} ${formatMeridian(h)}`

const formatHour = (h = 0) =>
  h === 0 ? "12" : String(h)

const formatMinute = (m = 0) =>
  m < 10 ? `0${m}` : String(m)

const formatMeridian = (h = 0) =>
  h < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"

const times =
  [ "00:00", "00:01", "01:23", "11:59", "12:00", "12:01", "13:22", "23:59", "24:00", "24:01", "25:00", "27:45" ]

times.forEach(t => console.log(t, "->", format24(t, to12)))
```

---

**invalid times**

If the time is completely malformed, we should probably `throw` an error to let the caller know the input time cannot be converted reliably -

```js
const format24 = (time = "00:00", formatter = String) =>
{ const [ match, h = 0, m = 0 ] =
    time.match(/^(\d\d):(\d\d)$/) || []

  if (match === undefined)
    throw Error("invalid 24-hour time")

  // ...
}

format24("foo", to12)     // Error: invalid 24-hour time
format24("1:23", to12)    // Error: invalid 24-hour time
format24("123:456", to12) // Error: invalid 24-hour time
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, Ori :D

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Good to see that you split the problem into separate functions. So its still functional programming but not difficult to grasp